# Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'RouteChildrenProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am following an online tutorial on a MERN stack app build. I have been getting this error **"has no exported member"** for '**RouteChildrenProps && RouteComponentProps**'. So I checked for similar errors on stackoverflow and I noticed they were all referring to replace ***RouteComponentProps*** with **useNavigate()**.

My problem is that I don't know how to implement the function useNavigate() in this code block

```
    <Routes>
    {routes.map((route, index) => {
      return (
        <Route
          key={index}
          exact={route.exact}
          path={route.path}
          element={route.component}
          render={(routeProps: RouteChildrenProps<any>) => (
            <route.component {...routeProps} />
          )}
         />
        );
     })}
   </Routes>
```

And also this error **Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)**.

Pls you can check out the block of codes on this codesandboxlink https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sea-idup5t?file=/src/App.tsx:264-673 for closer inspection

Comment: Hello.  I was working on the same tutorial and I went ahead and posted a similar question and was able to get an answer.  Thought I'd share it with you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382968/routechildrenprops-is-not-an-exported-member/76383378?noredirect=1#comment134690853_76383378