# RouteChildrenProps is not an exported member

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting the below error pointing to 'RouteChildrenProps':

[image]

I am just trying to get through a tutorial but I got stuck here.  Here is the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteChildrenProps, Routes } from 'react-router';
import routes from './config/routes';

export interface IApplicationProps {}

const Application: React.FunctionComponent<IApplicationProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      {routes.map((route, index) => {
        return <Route 
          key={index} 
          exact={route.exact} 
          path={route.path} 
          render={(routeProps: RouteChildrenProps<any>) =>
            <route.component {...routeProps} />} />;
          }
      )}
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default Application;
```

The tutorial itself did not encounter this issue. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Router v6 removed route props, these are a v4/5 export. The [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route) component API changed significantly from v4/5 to v6. There are no route props, no `exact` prop since routes are now ***always*** exactly matched, and all routed content is rendered on a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, e.g. JSX, value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router';
import routes from './config/routes';

export interface IApplicationProps {}

const Application: React.FunctionComponent<IApplicationProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      {routes.map((route) => {
        const Component = route.component;
        return (
          <Route 
            key={route.path} 
            path={route.path} 
            element={<Component />}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

If any of the routed component need to access what was previously passed via props, they should use the provided React hooks: [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) for `navigate` function that replaced `useHistory`, [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) for route path parameters, [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) for the `location` object, etc.

Comment: I was able to use your example to get rid of my error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [react-router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router) plugin, it's exported members as bellows. It does not contain `RouteChildrenProps`, It means you are unable to use that property. Please check whether you are using which version of react-router you are using (in this answer I'm referring react-router v6.11.2). Sometimes now this property can be deprecated.

[react-router/packages/react-router/index.ts](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.ts)

```
    // Expose react-router public API
export type {
  ActionFunction,
  ActionFunctionArgs,
  AwaitProps,
  Blocker as unstable_Blocker,
  BlockerFunction as unstable_BlockerFunction,
  DataRouteMatch,
  DataRouteObject,
  Fetcher,
  Hash,
  IndexRouteObject,
  IndexRouteProps,
  JsonFunction,
  LazyRouteFunction,
  LayoutRouteProps,
  LoaderFunction,
  LoaderFunctionArgs,
  Location,
  MemoryRouterProps,
  NavigateFunction,
  NavigateOptions,
  NavigateProps,
  Navigation,
  Navigator,
  NonIndexRouteObject,
  OutletProps,
  Params,
  ParamParseKey,
  Path,
  PathMatch,
  Pathname,
  PathPattern,
  PathRouteProps,
  RedirectFunction,
  RelativeRoutingType,
  RouteMatch,
  RouteObject,
  RouteProps,
  RouterProps,
  RouterProviderProps,
  RoutesProps,
  Search,
  ShouldRevalidateFunction,
  To,
};
```

If you want to implement a simple route in your application you can follow the bellow mechanism (remember for this I have used the typescript approach)

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Status } from "./interfaces/IAuth";
import CardPage from "./pages/CardPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import ListPage from "./pages/ListPage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/Login";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/Register";

const protectedRouter = createBrowserRouter(
    [
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <HomePage />
        },
        {
            path: "/list-component",
            element: <ListPage />
        },
        {
            path: "/card-page",
            element: <CardPage />
        },
    ],
    { basename: '/react-fundamentals' }
);

const publicRouter = createBrowserRouter(
    [
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <LoginPage />
        },
        {
            path: "/register",
            element: <RegisterPage />
        },
        {
            path: "/home",
            element: <HomePage />
        },
        {
            path: "*",
            element: <Navigate to="/" replace />
        }
    ],
    { basename: '/react-fundamentals' }
);

const AppRouter: React.FC<{ status?: Status }> = ({ status }) => {

    const selectedConfig = (status === 'authenticated') ? protectedRouter : publicRouter;

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={selectedConfig} />
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How do I go about checking which version of react-router I am using?  Or better yet, how do I go about updating the plugin so I can use it?  Or is there something else I should be using?

Comment: Are you using react-router or react-router-dom ? and you can simply check on package.json file

Comment: Forgive me - I am still new to React.  To answer your question, I guess I am using react-router.  But, I did try to update the import to react-router-dom but still received the same error.

Comment: Yah it comes because the latest version of react-router and react-router-dom does not have the property of `RouteChildrenProps`

Comment: Any thoughts as to how I can update this so I don't see the error anymore?

Comment: Looks like I am indeed using react-router-dom 6.11.2

Comment: If that is so please use my updated code to implement the routing. and follow the documentation https://reactrouter.com/en/main

Comment: Please refer to this sample repo to identify how routing works with react-router-dom.https://github.com/Kasun002/gw-stack-overflow